# Can the Raspberry Pi be a remote content delivery device?

Tags: networking, access-point

I have a limited understanding of how networking works but I am trying to use the Raspberry Pi to deliver content to users that are connected wirelessly (ideally through wifi) over a local network.

The scenario is that you are for example in a field, the raspberry pi is powered via a battery and a user can approach the Pi, join the network, and then navigate to the Pi's local ip via their preferred web browser and view the content delivered via the Pi's webserver.

Does the Pi have this capability or do i need a router with a wireless access point to be powered in the field as well and have the Pi directly wired over ethernet to the router, and then the user connects to the routers wireless access point?

Comment: the title question does not match the question in the body of the post

Comment: Basically you seem to be asking if the Raspberry Pi can act as a stand alone Access Point, which it can.

Comment: @StarCat okay thank you, while i have you here would you happen to have any resources which document this and/or keywords to search for?

Comment: You can search for "Raspberry pi as a standalone access point", which will turn up several tutorials. Like [this one from The Raspberry Pi Guide](https://raspberrypi-guide.github.io/networking/create-wireless-access-point). The last part of this tutorial deals with routing WiFi from your access point to the internet, but that isn't relevant in your situation.